# Android Eclipse How Close Class

Tags: java, android, class, kill

How can I close a Activity Class when the other is already loading?
II can on the subject, unfortunately no data found either on google or here.

Start Class if second Class = load = ture then close Start Class

Thank you

Comment: it is not clear what you mean by `close`, `class` and `loading`. be more specific.

Comment: Do you mean closing the editor tab? Your question should be edited to become more specific.

Comment: No a the simpel activity Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android handles "closing" or a better way of saying that is it handles the background resources of activities. If you start or end an activity Android's activity lifecycle moves on for that activity.

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

If you want to manage what happens when certain points of a certain activities lifecycle is reached you can simply override those methods like so..

```
@Override
protected void onPause() { 
    // Do stuff when this activty is paused.
}
```

Comment: Fine thank you helped me.sometimes I'm still in my vb.net head inside. ^^